# HTML5 video tag for livestreaming

Tags: html, video, video-streaming, html5-video

I want to know if the HTML5 `<video>` tag can be used for live streaming apart from other complicated methods, like using other servers like cam streams. If it's possible, I want to see a basic example code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use an encoder (e.g. VLC or FFmpeg) into packetize your input stream
   to OGG format. For example, in this case I used VLC to packetize
   screen capture device with this code:

   > C:\Program Files\VideoLAN\VLC\vlc.exe -I dummy screen://
   >   :screen-fps=16.000000 :screen-caching=100
   >   :sout=#transcode{vcodec=theo,vb=800,scale=1,width=600,height=480,acodec=mp3}:http{mux=ogg,dst=127.0.0.1:8080/desktop.ogg}
   >   :no-sout-rtp-sap :no-sout-standard-sap :ttl=1 :sout-keep
2. Embed this code into a `<video>` tag in your HTML page like that:

   `<video id="video" src="http://localhost:8080/desktop.ogg" autoplay="autoplay" />`

This is like a live streaming of desktop. performance might be low but yes livestreaming is supported. Even camera streaming, it just depends on the url you pass to video tag.

Answer (score 0):

was in intended for live video. What @Susheel Singh said is true, but it will not work in IE or chrome, and requires a custom server component. It also limits you to a pretty inferior video codec (Thora, but Opus audio is pretty good). The only container that is supported by all browsers is MP4. But MP4 can not (sanely) support live video. What you need is to use fMP4 and MSE for live video. Using a player like video.js will simplify this a lot.